# Validate field from controller in CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp

I am having a problem. I have the field `ordertypes` in my `$this->request->data['Workposition']`. This field is not a field from the `Workposition` model, but i need to validate this field not being empty. This is list of three checkboxes( when the checkbox is selected it is `0`, else it is `1` ). So, i need to add a validation direct in my controller, so that at least one checkbox is set to `1`(is selected). 
I was trying

```
if (all three checkboxes are set to `0`) 
$this->Workposition->validationErrors['ordertypes'] = __('Choose at least one ordertype');
```

but it isn't work, because this field is not a field of this `Workposition` model. Adding `$this->Workposition->set($this->request->data);` or `$this->Workposition->validates();` did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a try catch block in your controller action and throw an exception if the all three checkboxes are empty.

```
public function myControllerMethod()
{
    try {
        if (all three checkboxes are zero) {
            throw new Exception('Select a checkbox');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->data = array(
            'sucess' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php